# "And was Jerusalem builded here" - in the early 1800's was "builded" standard usage?

Tags: etymology, poetry, archaicisms

In the poem "[Jerusalem](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/54684)" by William Blake the line ...

> And was Jerusalem builded here

... appears.

Today I think most people would write that line as ...

> And was Jerusalem built here

.

I'm curious to know when Blake wrote the poem, in the first decade of the 1800's, was using 'builded' in that way an accepted usage or did Blake invent that usage to fit the rhythm of the poem ?

Comment: It was likely archaic at the time, but that would not have prevented Blake from using it if it fit his meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "*builded*"  is an archaic form for the past of:.

To [build](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/build):

> - verb,   built ***or (Archaic) builded;***

(Dictionary.com)

[Build](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=build&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - late Old English byldan "construct a house," verb form of bold "house.Rare in Old English; in Middle English it won out over more common Old English timbran (see timber). Modern spelling is unexplained. Figurative use from mid-15c. Of physical things other than buildings from late 16c. Related: ***Builded (archaic); built; building***.

(Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=builded%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuilded%3B%2Cc0): builded

Comment: Thanks for the good answer and also for introducing me to some useful online resources of which I was unaware.